# Performance issue with Set union in Scala

Tags: performance, scala, set, union

I just encountered a strange behavior in the Scala Set API. Here is my function stripped of what's related to the rest of the project

```
def grade(...): Double = {
  val setA: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  val setB: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  if ((setA size) == 0 || (setB size) == 0) return 0
  else return (setA & setB size) / (setA | set B size)
}
```

This function is called a lot of time inside a loop, and the whole loop is executed in around 4.5 sec. But when a replace the size of the union by the sum of the sizes (a gross approximation), in order to test the influence of the union operation, the time of execution is reduce to around 0.35 sec...

```
def grade(...): Double = {
  val setA: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  val setB: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  if ((setA size) == 0 || (setB size) == 0) return 0
  else return (setA & setB size) / (setA size + set B size)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can't compare a simple operation like a sum of 2 `Ints` with the `union` operation of 2 Sets. I expect the performance of these operations to be very different, specially if your Sets contain a lot of elements.

You don't need a union because you already do an intersection. Try the following:

```
def grade: Double = {
  val setA: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  val setB: HashSet = // get from somewhere else
  if ((setA size) == 0 || (setB size) == 0) return 0
  else {
     val inter = setA & setB size
     return inter / ((setA size) + (setB size) - inter)
  }
}
```

However, I find your measurement a little odd because I expected both operations (union and intersect) to take around the same amount of time O(n). Removing the union should improve the performance by half (2s)...

Comment: yeah, thank you for the trick, that's what I used as a quick patch. But I'm categoric: there is an issue with union. The proof is that using your trick, the execution time is roughly the same as with my version with only the sum. And this trick works only if you need just the size, and not the actual union set.

Comment: @Simon Bouget - Does set intersection have the same performance as union? Change the code above to do the union rather than the intersection, and then use the size of the union to calculate the size of the intersection. If that has similar performance to the union then it's probably just a problem with *O(1)* operations (e.g. adding the sizes) vs *O(n)* operations (e.g. actually performing the union of two sets).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using parallel collections, by any chance? Union is performed in a sequential manner, so any parallel collection is first converted into a sequential collection. That might account for the performance.

Other than that, union is about O(n), so you are going form O(n) to O(1), which makes a lot of difference.

Comment: No I'm not using parallel collections.

As for your other point, I guess intersection is also O(n) and I got similar performances with my first version with only sums and the solution of bruno conde calculating the size of union from the size of intersection.

I posted on Scala bugtracker, and they seem to consider my example as a faulty behavior there.